# Why doesn't property x exist on type Y, even after module augmentation?

Tags: javascript, typescript, node-modules

I'm messing around with modules but came across this scenario that I can't fully grasp. I have everything set up like so:

```
import MyTesterImpl from "./MyTesterImpl";

declare module "./MyTesterImpl" {
  interface MyTesterImpl {
    augmented: boolean;
  }
}

const main = async (): Promise<void> => {
  let testy: MyTesterImpl = {
    basicA: "hey",
    basicB: "there"
  } as MyTesterImpl;

  testy.augmented = true;
};

main();
```

Where I have MyTestImpl defined as:

```
export default class MyTesterImpl {
  public basicA: string;
  public basicB: string;

  constructor(a: string, b: string) {
    this.basicA = a;
    this.basicB = b;
  }

  showStuff() {
    console.log(`${this.basicA} ${this.basicB}`);
  }
}
```

Using a tsconfig defined as such:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom", "es6", "es2017", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.d.ts", "**/*.spec.ts"],
  "include": ["./**/*.ts"]
}
```

Even after adding the module augmentation in order to append the augmented field to the MyTesterImpl class, the compiler still throws the error that:

```
Property 'augmented' does not exist on type 'MyTesterImpl'.
```

You can see a reproducible example for the issue [**here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-wind-9un2wx?file=/src/index.ts).

I've been staring at this for hours and I can't find out why the error keeps persisting. I'm pretty positive I can do module augmentation between a class and interface as long as they share the same name, so I don't think that's the issue. And I made sure to point to the class file path when declaring the module for augmentation.

Everything looks in place to me; what am I missing here?

Comment: Could you provide a link to a web IDE that demonstrates this issue?  It would be a lot easier for someone to diagnose/fix the problem if they don't have to spend effort just trying to reproduce it.

Comment: Yeah my bad, I should have included the tsconfig file too probably. It's only 3 files (including  the tsconfig), but I just meshed it all into one for a reproducible example. I've appended the link to the example above.

Comment: I don't think the TypeScript playground presents these kinds of issues justice as a real web IDE like codesandbox, which I have made one of this problem [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-wind-9un2wx?file=/src/index.ts). By the way, why do you need to do this?

Comment: @caTS I'm not sure I completely follow. For me, the same error I am getting in my IDE is popping up in the TS Playground. Am I misinterpreting what you said? As for the purpose of this, it was only to deduce what could be causing a bigger problem I was having. I was trying to augment a 3rd party module and this issue came up, so I decided to make a smaller example to figure out why that would be happening, but the same error persisted even trying to augment my own module.

Comment: You can [quite easily](https://tsplay.dev/NdYKym) fix the Playground issue but you will not be able to translate that to your multi-file problem.  We really need a multi-file web IDE project to reproduce, unfortunately, like the one caTS provided.

Comment: Augmenting your own module is actually a little different than augmenting a third-party module. Your "own module" is probably using relative paths. Relative paths are treated slightly differently when augmenting them.

Comment: @jcalz Ah ok, now I see the importance there. Sorry about that, I had never had to reproduce a multi-file example. Good to know now. Is caTS provided example  sufficient to work with now? With their example, for me at least, I still see the error persist. Which brings me back to my initial question of why is that happening?

Comment: @caTS interesting, I didn't read that anywhere yet. In what way(s) are they treated different and could that be related to the problem here?

Comment: The first thing I tried in the code sandbox was moving the entire augmentation into an ambient declaration file (how you would with third-party modules), and whadya know, relative paths aren't allowed in ambient declaration files.

Comment: So, it looks like a TS bug, [ms/TS#14080](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14080), whereby you can't augment a class exported as `default`.  If you can change it to a regular named export it should work, but I don't know if you have that option.  I can write that up as an answer if you want.

Comment: @jcalz Damn, for my mini-example, that will definitely fix the issue. But the only export from the 3rd party module I'm using is a default export, so it's not looking too good :( Is there a way to route a 3rd party default export through another custom module which could then export it with a name?

Comment: Probably?  That issue has such a suggestion in it.  I can try to look into it when I get a chance

Comment: Looks like [this version](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-satoshi-j1zyiu?file=/src/index.ts).  Does that constitute an answer along with the ms/TS#14080 info if I write it up?  Or am I still missing something?  And could you update the question to point to the actual [mre] and not the Playground link?

Comment: Yep, that serves as a working solution in my case. Although I did see another person mention that other functionality in their code broke after implementing that. So far so good for me, though. I'll update the link accordingly.

Comment: Okay I will write an answer when I get a chance, although I see SO will be down for maintenance during the time I am most likely to be available 

Comment: I'm confused - are you declaring a module with the same name as a file in an attempt to override the file's functionality? Seems hacky, are you just trying this out to learn more about how it works?

Comment: Nevermind, just looked it up. Can't believe this is an actual thing that people do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a bug in TypeScript whereby classes exported as `default` cannot be [merged](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) into; see [microsoft/TypeScript#14080](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14080).  The issue in GitHub has been open for a long time and is marked as being on the "Backlog", so I wouldn't count on it being fixed anytime soon.

A [workaround mentioned in the issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14080#issuecomment-624676706) is to re-export the class as a named export, and then merge into *that*.  It would look something like

```
// ./MyTesterImplRepackaged.ts
import MyTesterImpl from "./MyTesterImpl";
export { MyTesterImpl };
```

and then

```
// ./index.ts
import { MyTesterImpl } from "./MyTesterImplRepackaged";

declare module "./MyTesterImplRepackaged" {
  interface MyTesterImpl {
    augmented: boolean;
  }
}

const main = async (): Promise<void> => {
  let testy: MyTesterImpl = {
    basicA: "hey",
    basicB: "there"
  } as MyTesterImpl;

  testy.augmented = true; // okay
};
```

It's not pretty, but it seems to work, at least for your example code.

[CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-satoshi-j1zyiu?file=/src/index.ts)